# Django: Query `id__in` with UUIDs

Tags: python, django

In Django, we can use the `id__in` query with a queryset to filter down a queryset based on a list of IDs. However, by default this will fail if your IDs are UUIDs. So this will not work and throw the error:

```
LINE 1: ...OM "items_character" WHERE "items_character"."id" IN (SELECT...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

```
    def foos(self):
        """
        Returns the user's owned foos.
        """
        # Todo: Cache & Bust On Update
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Foo)
        owned = Ownership.objects.filter(user=self, content_type=content_type)
        return objects.filter(id__in=owned.values_list("object_id", flat=True))
```

However, the following will work, if we manually convert the entire thing to UUID. Is there a way to make this work without this iteration over the set?

```
    def foos(self):
        """
        Returns the user's owned foos.
        """
        # Todo: Cache & Bust On Update
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Foo)
        owned = Ownership.objects.filter(user=self, content_type=content_type)
        owned_ids = list(owned.values_list("object_id", flat=True))
        test = []
        for fid in owned_ids:
            test.append(uuid.UUID(cid))
        return Foo.objects.filter(id__in=test)
```

Comment: Could we see your corresponding `models.py` for the Ownership model...

Comment: The problem might be in the way the foreign keys are stored (char, not uuid). So indeed, you need to cast the `object_id` foreign keys to uuid. Have you tried casting in the queryset itself using the [`Cast` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#cast)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the model lookup you're performing, is your id field of type, UUID or char?

```
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

**Or**

The more likely issue could be with the QuerySet not being cast as a list, for example, maybe change the line to this:

```
return objects.filter(id__in=list(owned.values_list("object_id", flat=True)))
```

Comment: The second suggestion will perform two queries, in order to first produce the `list`. But I think the problem is that the UUID is saved as `uuid` field in postgresql but the foreign key is saved as `char`. Not sure if this could be the mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an easier way of resolving this issue. That is by using [reverse relationship between models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/). For example:

If you have a relationship between Ownership and Foo is like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
   # fields

class Ownership(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then you can use

```
Foo.objects.filter(ownership__user=self, ownership__content_type=content_type)
```

If you have a `related_name` in ForignKey, for example:

```
foo = models.ForignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owners')
```

Then use it like this for querying:

```
Foo.objects.filter(owners__user=self, owners__content_type=content_type)
```

Advantage of this solution is, you do not have to make multiple queries to DB.

Comment: This is the more complete answer - it's always preferencial to limit the number of queries, and on first glance this looks very efficient on the DB layer - upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

While I think the approach of ruddra is definitely the better approach, i.e. directly querying on the reverse relationship, if you ever need to query to match a `uuid` field to a `char` field, you can use the `Cast()` function:

```python
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

owned = Ownership.objects.filter(user=self, content_type=content_type)
owned = owned.annotate(foo_as_uuid=Cast('foo_id', output_field=models.UUIDField()))
return Foo.objects.filter(id__in=owned.values_list('foo_as_uuid'))
```